# HTML to formatted text

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Are there any java APIs which does similar action like Html.fromHtml() as in Android? JSoup does parse and remove the tags but the output is not a formatted one.
eg:

```
<ol type="1">
 <li>Test1</li>
 <ol type="a">
  <li>TestA1</li>
  <li>TestB1</li>
 </ol>
 <li>Test2</li>
 <ol type="a">
  <li>TestA2</li>
  <li>TestB2</li>
 </ol>
</ol>
```

should give me something like

1. Test1

   a. TestA1

   b. TestB1
2. Test2

   a. TestA2

   b. TestB2

Comment: I think that some of the JComponets can render HTML, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: i am looking to covert some similar html tags to normal format text to a file

Comment: You may be on your own then. Check out the StringTokenizer class.

Comment: You can do this with jsoup, but you have to constrcut the list by your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's *no* api for **jsoup-to-"formated text"**, but you can convert lists by your own:

1. **iterate** over all **childs** of the `ul` / `ol` element which is the root of the list
2. if ***item***: format and add the output String
3. if ***sublist***: do *1.* - but with the sublist element - and add the result

### Example:

In this example i use the `type` attribute to determine what kind of bullet is required and use the character (!) to index the items. If there's no proper attribute, char `1` is used.

### Implementation:

```
/**
 * Convert the Listelement <code>root</code> to a formated string-representation.
 * 
 * @param root      Rootelement of the list (normally 'ul' or 'ol' tag)
 * @param depth     Depth of the list (<code>=0</code> for root element)
 * @return          List as String
 */
public String createList(Element root, int depth)
{
    final String indentation = createIndentation(depth); // create indentation
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    final String typeAttr = root.attr("type"); // Get the character used as bullet (= 'type' attribute)
    char type = typeAttr.isEmpty() ? '1' : typeAttr.charAt(0); // if 'type' attribute: use it, else: use '1' instead

    for( Element sub : root.children() ) // Iterate over all Childs
    {
        // If Java < 7: use if/else if/else here
        switch( sub.tagName() ) // Check if the element is an item or a sublist
        {
            case "li": // Listitem, format and append
                sb.append(indentation).append(type++).append(". ").append(sub.ownText()).append("\n");
                break;
            case "ol": // Sublist
            case "ul":
                if( !sub.children().isEmpty() ) // If sublist is not empty (contains furhter items)
                {
                    sb.append(createList(sub, depth + 1)); // Recursive call for the sublist
                }
                break;
            default: // "Illegal" tag, do furhter processing if required - output as an example here
                System.err.println("Not implemented tag: " + sub.tagName());
        }
    }

    return sb.toString(); // Return the formated List
}


/**
 * Create an Indentationstring of <code>length</code> blanks.
 * 
 * @param length    Size of indentation
 * @return          Indentationstring
 */
private String createIndentation(int length)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

    for( int i=0; i<length; i++ )
    {
        sb.append(' ');
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

### Testcode:

```
    Document doc = ... // Load / parse your document here

    Element listRoot = doc.select("ol").first(); // Select the root-element (!) of the list here. 
    final String output = createList(listRoot, 0); // Convert the list

    System.out.println(output); // Ouput
```

### Result:

**Input (HTML):**

```
<ol type="1">
    <li>Test1</li>
    <ol type="a">
        <li>TestA1</li>
        <li>TestB1</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <ol type="a">
        <li>TestA2</li>
        <li>TestB2</li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

**Output:**

```
1. Test1
 a. TestA1
 b. TestB1
2. Test2
 a. TestA2
 b. TestB2
```

Thats it! :-)

Comment: Thanks ollo. I had done something similar that time when I posted the question and did not get an answer. Nice implementation though!